# Major problems after trying to install Spotify

Tags: 14.04, spotify

I wanted to get the Spotify Linux app but I must have stuffed up the relatively [simple instructions](https://www.spotify.com/au/download/linux/) as now I can't update anything and I keep getting notifications telling me a major error has occurred.

Can someone help me either to remove this or repair it please? I'm somewhat new to Ubuntu, still a bit of a newbie but know basic stuff so please be detailed with any help :)

I'm on 14.04 running dual boot

```
C:~$ sudo apt-get purge spotify 

E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list E: The list of sources could not be read. 
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list 
E: The list of sources could not be read
```

Comment: Please post the exact message.

Comment: Also include the instructions you followed to install Spotify as a link.

Comment: Shoot, my bad I meant to post it! Sorry haha!

C:~$ sudo apt-get purge spotify
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.


And here's the site for Spotify;

https://www.spotify.com/au/download/linux/

Comment: Please [edit your post](http://askubuntu.com/posts/780769/edit) with the content of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju I don't know what you mean by content?

Comment: Open a terminal and run `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list` it will open a text file in the terminal, copy the contents here.

Comment: @MarkKirby I cut out my username that's why it said C:

I'm not running sandbox or anything like that, I partitioned and dual boot

Comment: @MarkKirby --

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install spotify-client

Comment: That is the content of the file? If so, you've completely messed up.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju correct. I was trying to follow the instructions on the website I gave but I have clearly stuffed it up haha. Is there any way I can keep it and fix it? I mean I do want it but if I have to remove it then I will.

Comment: I just installed it, it is hard to see how you went wrong, did you run all of the commands? My sources list says `deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free`, open yours in a text editor as root and swap that information for `deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free`, then run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: I feel stupid as hell but as I said I'm quite new to Ubuntu and coming from Windows where everything is auto I'm struggling just a tad haha. Can you break down the commands I have to put into terminal please @MarkKirby?

Comment: Yes, first run `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list` then delete every thing in that file and replace it with `deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free` then save it and run `sudo apt-get update` in terminal and try remove spotify again.

Comment: To remove it the command is `sudo apt-get purge spotify-client`

Comment: `code` Package 'spotify-client' is not installed, so not removed `code`

Comment: OK that is good output, the source is fixed and you have not installed it yet, just run `sudo apt-get install spotify-client` and it should install.

Comment: Positive note though; I can now get updates for all other packages

Comment: Yep, you should be fixed now.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark, that did it! I have updates and Spotify client now! Your help is greatly appreciated mate!

Comment: If I summarize this as an answer, please click the check mark next to it so others can know this is the correct solution.

Comment: I would but there's no check mark, only a star :/

Comment: Next to the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how this happened (perhaps someone can enlighten me) but the solution is simple.

Open /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list as root

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

Remove all information from the file and replace it with

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

Save the file and update the sources

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install spotify

```
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

Comment: Cheers for the help mate!